# How do I map a list of objects to return a specific property in my ASP.NET API application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've made a basic Web API and I'm working on a list of games and their platforms.  When I hit my API endpoint with postman, I see the following information.

```
[
    { 
        Title: "God of War, 
        Platform: "Xbox"
    },
    { 
        Title: "Grand Theft Auto", 
        Platform: "Xbox"
    }
]
```

However, I don't need to return the platform from my API, only the title.  So the array should look like this when my API endpoint is hit:

```
[ 
    "God of War", 
    "Grand Theft Auto" 
]
```

If this was JavaScript then you could easily map this but with C# I'm not sure how.  Below is my code starting with the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/v1/api/games")]
public IEnumerable<Games> GetGames()
{
    List<Games> games = new()
    {
        new Games
        {
            Title = "Hunted",
            IsPrimary = false
        },
        new Games
        {
            Title = "Grand Theft Auto",
            IsPrimary = false
        }
    };

    //var test = games.Select(x => x.Title).ToArray(); Doesn't seem to work
       
    return games;
}
```

The model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class Games
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool? IsPrimary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I map my list to return only the titles in the way I've shown?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change your method signature to

```
IEnumerable<string> GetGames()
```

and return

```
games.Select(x => x.Title);
```

Or mark the Platform property on Game class with attribute `[Ignore]` if you want to ignore it completely in your overall application.